# HTML5 tag <video> number of requests

Tags: javascript, html, httprequest

I'm developing a simple web application with one video using `<video>` tag. I want to count the number of requests that my application does to load the video from the server. My goal is to show in real-time the number of requests in my HTML page.

Chrome dev tools does this counting in Network tab, I want to do the same via JavaScript. Is it possible?

Example: when i reload my page with chrome dev tools placed in tab "netowrk" i can see all the requests that my client do to the server to load the page. When the video is playing i can see all the request (206 partial content) that serve to load the video. Chrome dev tools shows a counter of all requests in the left at the bottom. I want my application counts these requests.

I want to design an application that shows connection stats when playing the video, one of this is the number of requests the client does to load the video.
I tried with "resource timing API" but i don't know if is the right way to attack the problem.
I'm using apache tomcat as webserver.

Comment: No, without some server-side backplane

Comment: Do you want to record the number of loads or the number of *plays*? For example, do you want to count when I sit on your page and hit F5 a hundred times, or would you rather count it as a hit when I've watched, say, at least 30 seconds of your video?

Comment: Keep in mind: I believe the way the <video> tag commonly works is with multiple requests going back and forth from the server to give the stream chunks correctly. So, if you're trying to track the total number of times *a video* is requested, this might be the wrong approach.